# Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30) WiFi not working

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04, atheros

Using ***Ubuntu 16.04 LTS***

By using this command `lspci -nn | grep Atheros` I'm getting following o/p.

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
```

I'm not able to connect WiFi since last two days.(WiFi network/option not shown in icon and setting)

Following wireless info which is generated by script.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 01 Jun 2016 23:17 IST +0530

Booted last: 01 Jun 2016 00:00 IST +0530

Script from: 30 Apr 2015 17:23 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu (from ~/.dmrc)

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:098a]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0806]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2c81 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04ca:3015 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

acer_wmi               20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 acer_wmi
ath10k_pci             45056  0
ath10k_core           311296  1 ath10k_pci
ath                    32768  1 ath10k_core
mac80211              737280  1 ath10k_core
cfg80211              565248  3 ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    20480  3 acer_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  40960  3 i915,acer_wmi,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

enx5c93a28407e4 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enx5c93a28407e4' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.44.119  Bcast:192.168.44.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3677:1ce9:9557:bec0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12128 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14596 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5919220 (5.9 MB)  TX bytes:1476446 (1.4 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enx5c93a28407e4  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.44.1    0.0.0.0         UG    750    0        0 enx5c93a28407e4
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enx5c93a28407e4
192.168.44.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     750    0        0 enx5c93a28407e4

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bt
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceBt
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         bluez
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /org/bluez/hci0/dev_5C_51_88_3C_DE_E2
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enx5c93a28407e4
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     MotoG3 Network
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       45836b65-bb70-4067-aeaa-32479dee900f
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/6
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
BLUETOOTH.CAPABILITIES:                 NAP
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   45836b65-bb70-4067-aeaa-32479dee900f | MotoG3 Network
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.44.119/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.44.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.44.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.44.1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.44.119
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.44.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.44.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 3150
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.44.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 1800
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       expiry = 1464806473
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       host_name = kaushal-Aspire-E5-573G
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.44.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       vendor_encapsulated_options = ANDROID_METERED
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 192.168.44.1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::3677:1ce9:9557:bec0/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp2s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

enx5c93a28407e4  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enx5c93a28407e4  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[ath10k_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-3.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware.bin
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Driver support for Atheros QCA988X PCIe devices
author:         Qualcomm Atheros
srcversion:     8CBDAC7980FC042032AE6A6
depends:        ath10k_core
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           irq_mode:0: auto, 1: legacy, 2: msi (default: 0) (uint)
parm:           reset_mode:0: auto, 1: warm only (default: 0) (uint)

[ath10k_core]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_core.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Core module for QCA988X PCIe devices.
author:         Qualcomm Atheros
srcversion:     275C24567932534F3B81E01
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           debug_mask:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           uart_print:Uart target debugging (bool)
parm:           skip_otp:Skip otp failure for calibration in testmode (bool)
parm:           cryptmode:Crypto mode: 0-hardware, 1-software (uint)
parm:           rawmode:Use raw 802.11 frame datapath (bool)

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     3FCDBF7CE71CB8FB980D59D
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     A882F4FE63500846E1C859E
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     00D8DA6D3B739DDD31FFF50
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath10k_pci]
irq_mode: 0
reset_mode: 0

[ath10k_core]
cryptmode: 0
debug_mask: 0
rawmode: N
skip_otp: N
uart_print: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf]
options ath10k_core skip_otp=y

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

grep: /etc/udev/rules.d/*net*.rules: No such file or directory

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############
```

If you know something then please let me know how can I solve this issue and access WiFi.

I'm Using ACER Aspire E 15 (E5-573G-5147).

If you want some more information then let me know.

Comment: Please add the result of the following terminal command: `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just need firmware that Ubuntu has included in the latest linux-firmware version.  Install with

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb
```

Reboot

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'll let you know my o/p by today. I'm out right now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Internet connected your ethernet card.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) git
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y" |  tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/11/20/backports-20151120.tar.gz
tar zxvf backports-20151120.tar.gz
cd backports-20151120
make defconfig-wifi
make
make install
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
cp -r ath10k-firmware/QCA9377 /lib/firmware/ath10k/
cp /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
reboot
```

Whenever you upgrade your kernel you must run

```
exec sudo -i
cd backports-20151120
make clean
make defconfig-wifi
make
make install
```

Comment: *backports* is not needed as the driver is included by default in 16.04.