# How can I get "Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device e0b1 (rev 10)" working under Linux?

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, ethernet, atheros

I recently purchased a new laptop (MSI GT62VR Dominator Pro) that has an Ethernet card that does not work under Linux by default. I have tried installing the [alx driver](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/alx) with the instructions in their Github, which produces no change. I have also tried installing an additional linux-firmware package as described in the top answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/780608/network-controller-0280-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-30-wifi-not) question, which breaks wifi support as well.

```
$ lspci | grep "Ethernet"
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device e0b1 (rev 10)
```

What must  I do to use my laptop's ethernet port under Linux?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ethernet is an `Atheros Killer Gaming Network E2400`. If you Google for `Atheros e2400 driver` you'll get a good number of hits...

and this one looks promising...

```
http://askubuntu.com/questions/670347/is-there-any-way-to-install-atheros-e2400-drivers
```

I also noticed that the alx driver already exists in Ubuntu 16.10... and it shows support for the E0B1 variant... so if you're using an older version of Ubuntu, you might try booting the Ubuntu Live DVD 16.10 and see if the ethernet works out of the box...

update: It's been tested... and the ethernet port works in 16.10

```
$ modinfo alx
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Qualcomm Atheros(R) AR816x/AR817x PCI-E Ethernet Network Driver
author:         Qualcomm Corporation, 
author:         Johannes Berg 
srcversion:     148031F2236BBDAF23DA652
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001090sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E0B1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E0A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        mdio
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

Comment: I tried a 16.10 live usb. The ethernet port works there, but, ideally there is so way to install it in 16.04 -- I don't want to reinstall my system every few months.

Comment: You don't need to reinstall your system... just do an upgrade... it'll go from 16.04 to 16.10 and your ethernet port will work.